# How to delete AJAX validation errors when closing a modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

Merry Christmas!

I'm having issues deleting the AJAX validation errors. I have a script that resets the form once the 'Cancel' button is pressed but the validation errors do not disappear.

This is my modal registration form:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Registro</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="" name="registerform" id="signup1" method="POST" role="form">
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nombres</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ingresa tu(s) nombre(s)">
                  <span id="nameerror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Solo pueden ser letras</p> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">  
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lname"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Apellidos</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ingresa tus apellidos">
                  <span id="lnameerror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Solo pueden ser letras</p> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="genero">

                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

                <label for="masculino" class="btn btn-default active">
                <input type="radio" name="genero" id="masculino" autocomplete="off" checked value="M">
                Masculino
                </label>

                <label for="femenino" class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="genero" id="femenino" autocomplete="off" value="F">
                Femenino
                </label>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Correo electronico</label><span id="resultmail"></span>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Usuario</label><span id="result"></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ingresa tu usuario">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fecha de nacimiento</label>

                  <div class="row" id="fecha">

                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="day">

                                <option hidden>Dia</option>

                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>


                            </select>

                        </div>




                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="month">

                                <option hidden>Mes</option>

                                <option value="01">Enero</option>
                                <option value="02">Febrero</option>
                                <option value="03">Marzo</option>
                                <option value="04">Abril</option>
                                <option value="05">Mayo</option>
                                <option value="06">Junio</option>
                                <option value="07">Julio</option>
                                <option value="08">Agosto</option>
                                <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
                                <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                                <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                                <option value="12">Diciembre</option>

                            </select>

                        </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="year">
                                <option hidden>Año</option>
                                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                <option value="1964">1954</option>
                                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                                <option value="1918">1918</option>
                                <option value="1917">1917</option>
                                <option value="1916">1916</option>
                                <option value="1915">1915</option>
                                <option value="1914">1914</option>
                                <option value="1913">1913</option>
                                <option value="1912">1912</option>
                                <option value="1911">1911</option>
                                <option value="1910">1910</option>
                                <option value="1909">1909</option>
                                <option value="1908">1908</option>
                                <option value="1907">1907</option>
                                <option value="1906">1906</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Contrasena</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contrasena">
                  <span id="passerror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Debe ser mayor a 5 caracteres </p></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cpassword"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Confirma tu contrasena</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Vuelve a ingresar tu contrasena">
                  <span id="cpasserror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Debe coincidir con tu contrasena</p> </span>
                </div>





        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <input type="submit" id="btnregistrar" name="register" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrar"></input>

            <button type="button" id="btncerrar1" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>


        </div>
</form>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my email-check.php file:

```
<?php

 $host="localhost";
 $user="root";
 $pass="";
 $dbname="lr";

 $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);

 if($_POST['email']) 
 {
  $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email");
  $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
  $count=$stmt->rowCount();

  if($count>0){

    echo "<i class='fa fa-circle user-validation-w' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability'> Not Available</span>"; // No disponible

} else {

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        echo "<i class='fa fa-circle user-validation-w pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'> Ingresa un correo valido</span>";  // Correo invalido

    } else if ( $email = "") {

        echo "HOLA"; // No hay caracteres

    }else{

    echo "<i class='fa fa-circle user-validation-ok pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'> Available</span>";  // Disponible
}
}
}
?>
```

This is my user-check.js file

```
// Validate email while typing

$(document).ready(function()
{    
$("#email").keyup(function()
{  
var email = $(this).val(); 

if (email.length > 3)
{  
$("#resultmail").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin loading-icon"></i>');


 /*$.post("email-check.php", $("#reg-form").serialize())
 .done(function(data){
 $("#resultmail").html(data);
 });*/

 $.ajax({

 type : 'POST',
 url  : 'email-check.php',
 data : $(this).serialize(),
 success : function(data)
    {
          $("#resultmail").html(data);
       }
 });
 return false;

 }
 else
 {
  $("#resultmail").html('');
 }

 });


 });
```

And this is my clear-modal.js file, which resets the form fields:

```
// Clear modal after closing function
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
 });
 });
```

I know that some things might be wrong because I'm just starting but so far it's working for me. I just can't make the errors disappear once I close the modal. Would you mind helping me with that?

PD: some of the words are in Spanish because i'm from South-America.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your validation is manual (you create the errors yourself) so you should also remove them by yourself in the 'clear' function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
      $(this).find("i[class*='user-validation-'],span.availability").remove();
     //remove all <i> with class containing 'user-validation-' and all span.availability
   });
});
```

you can also simply add `$("#resultmail").empty();` since the errors go into that div.

Comment: I just tried that. The errors keep showing although the form is empty after I close and reopen the modal form.

Comment: did you try `$("#resultmail").empty();` ?

Comment: Nvm. I misspelled a word. WORKS GREAT. Thank you very much!

Comment: great! have a nice week

Comment: Thank you. You too, happy holidays!